# How GCM works ? How GCM idenfies the device to send Push Notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

how gcm push notifications are used ? how Gcm recognises that which push notification is related to which device ?
how should i send push notification without making use of GCM ?

Comment: This link has your answers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Messaging . Go through the reference link and technical details to dig it more. !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCM stands for Google Cloud Messaging. Every push notification receive on any Android device is sent by the GCM only.

sender -> GCM -> Android Device

when sender sends an push notification then it goes to GCM. GCM receives that push and forward it to particular Android Device by its Unique device id.

GCM can't deliver Push without Unique Device ID.

while implementing push notification there are two important things, application key and server key ... these are unique Keys.. using these keys GCM identifies the application to whom push notification is related.

for more information .. read push notifications on google developers document